# Rust by example: The ref pattern

Tags: rust

I have problems understanding the `ref` pattern in Rust. I am referring to https://rustbyexample.com/scope/borrow/ref.html

Here is the code I don't understand:

```
let point = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };

let _copy_of_x = {
    // `ref_to_x` is a reference to the `x` field of `point`
    let Point { x: ref ref_to_x, y: _ } = point;

    // Return a copy of the `x` field of `point`
    *ref_to_x
};
```

I get that the last `let` expression(?) is some sort of pattern matching. So it's my understanding `ref ref_to_x` should be equal to `0`, the `x` value of the original `point`.

But I don't understand what the `ref` actually does. When I add some code like this:

```
println!("x: {}", point.x);
println!("ref_to_x: {}", ref_to_x);
println!("*ref_to_x: {}", *ref_to_x);
```

I always get `0`, so there doesn't seem to be a difference. Somehow I'd expect a memory address for `ref_to_x` while `*ref_to_x` might be the dereferenced value again.

I can replace both `ref ref_to_x` and `*ref_to_x` with `myx` and the code still works. What's the difference? What does `ref` do exactly?

edit: after reading dbaupps answer and doing some addition with `ref_to_x` and `*ref_to_x` things got a bit clearer; you cannot add an integer to `ref_to_x` because it's a reference. I guess I got confused because there is no indication of a reference when you print one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ref` creates a pointer into the piece of memory that is being matched on, in this case, `ref_to_x` is pointing directly to the memory that stores `point.x`, it is the same as writing `let ref_to_x = &point.x` in this case.

The pattern is extremely important, as it allows one to reach deep inside complicated data-structures without disturbing the ownership hierarchy. For example, if one has `val: &Option<String>`, writing

```
match *val {
    Some(s) => println!("the string is {}", s),
    None => println!("no string"
}
```

is not legal, it gives an error like:

```
<anon>:3:11: 3:15 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
<anon>:3     match *val {
                   ^~~~
<anon>:4:14: 4:15 note: attempting to move value to here
<anon>:4         Some(s) => {}
                      ^
<anon>:4:14: 4:15 help: to prevent the move, use `ref s` or `ref mut s` to capture value by reference
<anon>:4         Some(s) => {}
                      ^
```

It is not legal to take ownership (move) out of a borrowed value, because that would possibly damage the thing from which the value was borrowed (violating its invariants, causing data to disappear unexpectedly, etc.).

So, one can instead use a reference to just point in the memory with a borrowing `&` reference.

---

There's a slight subtlety here because (a) `point` isn't borrowed, so it is OK to move out of `point` (which consumes ownership of `point` too, meaning it can't be used later unless reinitialised), and (b) the type `int` is `Copy`, so doesn't move ownership when used by value. This is why using `myx` instead works fine. If the type of `x` was, say, `String` (which isn't `Copy`) and `point` was borrowed, then the `ref` will be necessary.

Answer (score 26):

A reference created with `ref` is exactly the same as reference taken with `&`.

The difference is where they're allowed in the syntax. `ref` on the left side of an assignment is like adding `&` on the right side.

These expressions are equivalent:

```
let ref x1 = y;
let x2 = &y;
```

This redundancy exists because in pattern matching `&` is used to require that a reference exists already, rather than to make a new one:

```
let foo = 1;
match foo {
   ref x => {
       /* x == &1 */ 
       match x {
           &y => /* y == 1 */
       }
   },  
}
```

([discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-by-example/issues/390), and deeper explanation [why the patterns are like this](https://h2co3.github.io/pattern/))