# What's the difference between `&` and `ref`?

Tags: reference, rust

I understand how `&` works, but what is the difference between that and `ref`? Are they interchangeable?

The only information I found (because searching for symbols on Google doesn't work very well) is [this page on Rust By Example](http://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_pointers.html), but it doesn't explain the difference between the two. [The Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html) is not very informative, and `ref` is only listed on the [Patterns](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html) chapter. But it seems that `ref` is used outside that context too.

So, what are the uses of `ref`, and what's the difference to `&`?

Comment: *Very* related, but not exactly a duplicate, since it's not a comparsion between `ref` and `&`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911656/rust-by-example-the-ref-pattern

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ref` is used in patterns to bind a reference to an *lvalue* (an lvalue is a value you can take the address of, more or less).

It's important to understand that patterns go "backwards" from normal expressions, since they're used to **deconstruct** values.

Here's a simple example. Suppose we have this:

```
let value = 42;
```

We can bind a reference to `value` in two ways:

```
let reference1 = &value;
let ref reference2 = value;
```

In the first case, we use `&` as an operator to take the address of `value`. In the second case, we use the `ref` pattern to "deconstruct" an lvalue. In both cases, the type of the variable is `&i32`.

`&` can also be used in patterns, but it does the opposite: it deconstructs a reference by dereferencing it. Suppose we have:

```
let value = 42;
let reference = &value;
```

We can dereference `reference` in two ways:

```
let deref1 = *reference;
let &deref2 = reference;
```

Here, the type of both `deref1` and `deref2` is `i32`.

It's not always possible to write the same expression in two ways as shown here, however. For example, you cannot use `&` to take a reference to a value stored in an enum variant: you need to match on it. For example, if you want to take a reference to the value in a `Some`, you need to write:

```
match option {
    Some(ref value) => { /* stuff */ }
    None => { /* stuff */ }
}
```

since there's no way in Rust you can use the `&` operator to access the value otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, so definitions like `fn blah(ref a: i32) {}` are equivalent to `fn blah(a: &i32)`, when they can both be expressed?

Comment: @Kroltan No, they're not equivalent. A pattern (i.e. anything to the left of the `:`) in a function argument is purely an implementation detail, callers only see the types (i.e. things to the right of the `:`). The first case is equivalent to `fn blah(tmp: i32) { let ref a = tmp; ... }`. The first one is called like `blah(0)` while the second is called like `blah(&1)`. Of course, the function itself, the type of `a` is `&i32` in both case, it's just the external interface that differs.

Comment: @huon-dbaupp, does that mean that the ref variant will copy/move the value first?

Comment: `fn blah(ref a: i32) -> {}` is roughly equivalent to `fn blah(temp_a: i32) { let ref a = temp_a; }`.