# In a match, expected reference, found enum, error E0308

Tags: enums, reference, rust

I am working on a Reverse Polish Notation problem. In the `eval` function, I want to pass the input tokens as a reference, then iterate through it and using match to do something either `A` or `B`. But the program produces an error:

> expected reference, found enum `main::Token`.

I want to check the type of token here, but Rust doesn't seem to have a straightforward way to print out the type. What is the error source here?

```
pub enum Operator {
    // `+`
    Add, 
    // `-`
    Sub,
    // `*`
    Mul,
}

pub enum Token {
    Operator(Operator),
    Operand(isize),
}

pub fn eval(tokens: &[Token]) -> Option<isize> {       
    for token in tokens {
        // error here: expected reference, found enum `main::Token` 
        match token {
            Token::Operator(ref a) => println!("do something A"),
            Token::Operand(ref b) => println!("do something B"),
        };
    } 

    Some(5) 
}

fn main() { 
    // test input
    let input1 = Token::Operand(3);
    let input2 = Token::Operand(2);
    let sign1 = Operator::Add;
    let input3 = Token::Operator(sign1);
    eval(&[input1, input2, input3]);
}
```

My question is **not** a duplicate of [Matching on a reference to an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590549/matching-on-a-reference-to-an-enum), since add `ref` doesn't save it from the type mismatch error.

Comment: Additional info: when you're iterating through a `&[Token]`, the yielded items are references, not the values directly. Therefore `token` in your `for`-loop has the type `&main::Token` which is different from `main::Token`.

Comment: And [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423).

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, thanks that makes lots of sense, but if I use Token::Operator(ref a) => println!("do something A"), still not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: `token` has `&Token` type, and you're trying to match it as `Token` type. Use `match *token`, as suggested in the duplicate's answer. Using `ref` in a pattern only alters type of the variable inside the corresponding branch, but has no effect on the `match` itself.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, that really helps!!!

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, does  (ref a)   and  (& a) has the same meaning? Why I cannot use  Token::Operator(& a) => println!("do something A")?

Comment: @enaJ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33204483/234590