# What can ref do that references couldn't?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, language-design

What can `ref` do that references couldn't? Could

```
match value.try_thing() {
    &Some(ref e) => do_stuff(e),
    // ...
}
```

not be equally expressed by

```
match value.try_thing() {
    &Some(e) => do_stuff(&e),
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Complement: [Rust by example: The ref pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911656/rust-by-example-the-ref-pattern)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "avoidable". Is it necessary in *this* code? No. Is it necessary in *any* code? Kind of, yes, depending on how much you're willing to rewrite to avoid writing `ref`. Could the language have been designed without it? I suppose so, especially if something like default binding modes had been part of the original design, but that doesn't seem like a particularly interesting counterfactual to me... What's the point of this question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Editor's note** — this answer was posted [when the question was titled "Was Rust's ref keyword avoidable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58292554/3). The OP has since changed the title, making the phrasing of the answer less sensible.

No, it is not avoidable with your proposed syntax. Your syntax does not allow for taking a reference when otherwise a move would be permissable. In this example, `inner` is a copy of the integer from `val` and changing it has no effect on `val`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut val = Some(42);
    
    if let &mut Some(mut inner) = &mut val {
        inner += 1;
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", val); // Some(42)
}
```

The `ref` keyword is needed to force taking a reference:

```
fn main() {
    let mut val = Some(42);
    
    if let &mut Some(ref mut inner) = &mut val {
        *inner += 1;
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", val); // Some(43)
}
```

*Match ergonomics* allows writing this in a simpler manner:

```
fn main() {
    let mut val = Some(42);
    
    if let Some(inner) = &mut val {
        *inner += 1;
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

However, if we started with only this syntax, then we'd probably have the opposite problem and keyword, one to force a move instead; perhaps `Some(move inner)`. In that alternate universe, there'd be a question asking if the `move` keyword was avoidable.

See also:

- [How can the ref keyword be avoided when pattern matching in a function taking &self or &mut self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130932/155423)
- [How does Rust pattern matching determine if the bound variable will be a reference or a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56511328/155423)
- [Why is `ref` used instead of an asterisk in pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58184472/155423)
- [What is the syntax to match on a reference to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36590549/155423)
- [Rust by example: The ref pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27911656/155423)

Comment: This seems to suggest that only one of `ref` or `move` would have been strictly necessary, possibly at the cost of having the wrong default in certain scenarios.

Comment: @Ryan1729 recall that `move` is not a valid keyword in pattern matching today. We are already in a state where only one (`ref`) is necessary and we have the wrong default in certain scenarios. The OPs implicit assertion is that there's a world where no keyword is needed and the language can just Do The Right Thing.

Comment: Why not using & instead of `ref` here?: if let &mut Some(ref mut inner) = &mut val {

Comment: @frankelot I think the already-linked question and answer [Why is `ref` used instead of an asterisk in pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58184472/155423) covers that. Let me know if there's something missing.